# How to get cursor position or selection in slatejs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

I am creating a basic editor using slate.js and React.js.

I want to insert text inside the editor at current selected position when i click on a card outside the editor i.e. when i click on a card containing a text, the card on text should get inserted at the last cursor position in slate.js editor.

Comment: What's the code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get cursor position. Slate remembers selection when you click your button. You just need to insert content:

```
editor.insertBlock(...)
```

[image: Available options]